# How do you get resin to serve index.html by default if you navigate to a directory? (equivalent of DirectoryIndex in Apache)

Tags: java, resin

Is it possible to configure [Resin](http://caucho.com/resin/) to serve static files such that navigating to e.g. http://localhost:8888/foo/bar/ will serve the file foo/bar/index.html (without performing a redirect)? I can't find the answer in the Resin docs, though I might be looking in the wrong place.

The equivalent in Apache would be the DirectoryIndex directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I don't get the question, but [welcome-file-list](http://caucho.com/resin/doc/webapp-tags.xtp#welcome-file-list) seems to do just that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the welcome-file-list tag is used to specify this. 
See http://caucho.com/resin/doc/webapp-tags.xtp#welcome-file-list